# Hidden React components, how to "turn off" listeners/reduce performance overhead?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have a requirement that will see us have to render out the same instance of a react component in multiple positions in our grid and to show and hide those components based on screen width. E.g. our product module component is set to show at position 3 on mobile and 5 on desktop for example.

A concern that has been raised is around performance and the fact we will have multiple instances of the same component on the page (we have 6 breakpoints so worst case is a component will be rendered 6 times in different positions) several times all with listeners etc but only a few of them are actually visible. Is there a way we can essentially make a react component "dormant" unless it is actually visible thereby reducing the load on the page?

Comment: What is the component doing/listening to?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to put some **conditional rendering** on your component.

Read about it from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html).